# Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\InfoRevision" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\ChequeosRevision#$idrevision", got "integer" instead

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\InfoRevision" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\ChequeosRevision#$idrevision", got "integer" instead.

I had this problem, i cant insert on database , i let the files like decfault controller part, entities, and the orm

code of default, the info os on post

```
*entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('model_app');
           $chequeo = new ChequeosRevision();
           $chequeo->setidRevision($id2);
           $chequeo->setOk($ok);
           $chequeo->setNok($nok);
           $chequeo->setSosp($sospechoso);
           $chequeo->setNum($num);
           $chequeo->setNcheck($nombre);
           $chequeo->setNa($na);
           $chequeo->setRep($repeat);
           $entityManager->persist($chequeo);
           $entityManager->flush();

    Next part entity 1

    <code>
      /**
         * @var \AppBundle\Entity\InfoRevision
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\InfoRevision")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idrevision", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
        private $idrevision;
      /**
 * Set idrevision.
 *
 * @param int $idrevision
 *
 * @return ChequeosRevision
 */
public function setidRevision($idrevision)
{
    $this->idrevision = $idrevision;

    return $this;
}
    </code>

    and the orm

        enter code here

    <code>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping https://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
      <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\ChequeosRevision" table="chequeos_revision">
        <indexes>
          <index name="idrevision" columns="idrevision"/>
        </indexes>
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
          <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
        <field name="ok" type="boolean" column="ok" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="nok" type="boolean" column="nok" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="sosp" type="boolean" column="sosp" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="num" type="boolean" column="num" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="ncheck" type="string" column="ncheck" length="255" nullable="false">
          <options>
            <option name="fixed"/>
          </options>
        </field>
        <field name="na" type="boolean" column="na" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="rep" type="boolean" column="rep" nullable="false"/>
        <many-to-one field="idrevision" target-entity="InfoRevision" fetch="LAZY">
          <join-columns>
            <join-column name="idrevision" referenced-column-name="id"/>
          </join-columns>
        </many-to-one>
      </entity>
    </doctrine-mapping>

    </code>*
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the ID of the object, just pass the object as the error says (Doctrine is an ORM).

Comment: it give me null, and i iwant the id +1

Comment: He should have had a method to set revision not revision id. The annotations are good but the php is not according to annotations.

Comment: Mine was only a tip. Does the code is yours? Annotation needs an InfoRevision Object! Better read again the Doctrine docs?! :-) Also, I don't think you can mix Annotations with XML mapping...

Comment: i have the solution ty @gp_sflover